# How to Cut This String This Html With Script PHP

Tags: php, html

I am learning to grabbing data with curl.
This my code.

```
function readHTML($url){
 $data = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 $result = curl_exec($data);
 curl_close($data);
 return $result;}

    $codeHTML =  readHTML('http://website.com/');$ex1 = explode('ol class=tabcont>', $codeHTML); $ex2 = explode('/ol>', $ex1[1]);echo $ex2[0];
```

I Have a problem with this output html code.

```
<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
</ul>
```

I want to cut the code `<li></li>` with PHP so the code like it

```
<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
</ul>
```

How can i do it. sorry my english is bad. :)
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for pagination? Or just minimize the number of rows displayed on a single page

Comment: if you want to parse *existing* html, there's some options too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: no, the html is output from grabbing and shows like that and i want to minimize to five li tag. i want to use function explode but the code is same. 
thanks for editing :)

Comment: If you're grabbing html, please consider parsing it with the [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class. This will make your life easier, as you can easily delete nodes and just have 5 (or however many) `li` tags within `ul`.

Comment: @DaveChen `DomDocument` doesnt work with HTML.

Comment: @user3513136 I wouldn't recommend using explode for scraping HTML. There are great extensions made just for this type work.

Comment: hhhe,, i am just learning about PHP. i must study hard again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are grabbing this HTML, instead of being hard-coded. I feel using [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is appropriate.

```
<?php

$html = '<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
</ul>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$ul    = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0);
$count = 0;

$toRemove = array();

foreach ($ul->childNodes as $node)
    if ($node->tagName === 'li')
        if ($count++ >= 5)
            $toRemove[] = $node;
foreach ($toRemove as $node)
    $ul->removeChild($node);

$dom->removeChild($dom->firstChild);
$dom->replaceChild($dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $dom->firstChild);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/21059847639169):

```
<ul><li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>
<li>content</li>



</ul>
```

The empty lines are due to the new lines around the `<li>` tags. You can remove them too by checking for the `#text` as well.

Comment: @user3513136 If you are satisfied with this answer please accept it with a checkmark. I would ask again that you reconsider using explode to scrape html data. If anything changes, nothing will work.